# Mixing virtual forwards and virtual mailboxes in postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I am setting up a postfix server. The first thing I tried was to deliver mail to virtual mailboxes:

**main.cf**

```
[..]
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
```

**virtual_domains**

```
mydomain.com
```

**virtual_mailbox**

```
jasper@mydomain.com mydomain.com/jasper
```

This works.
Alternatively, I can use forwards on my virtual domain:

**main.cf**

```
[..]
virtual_alias_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_forwards
```

**virtual_domains**

```
mydomain.com
```

**virtual_forwards**

```
jasper2@mydomain.com myemail@gmail.com
```

This also works. However, if I try to use both at the same time, my logs show a warning that I shouldn't have the same domain in both `virtual_mailbox_domains` and `virtual_alias_domains` and only one of the two works.

This is what I want to accomplish, though, forward mail for some accounts on the virtual domain and store mail for other accounts on the same virtual domain. Is there any way to accomplish this with postfix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I posted this question, another idea that might solve this popped into my head. It wasn't the *exact* solution, but it lead me to the solution all the same. It's actually rather simple: you just have to specify the domain in `virtual_mailbox_domains` but not in `virtual_alias_domains` and it'll just work.

So:

**main.cf**

```
[..]
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_forwards
```

**virtual_domains**

```
mydomain.com
```

**virtual_mailbox**

```
jasper@mydomain.com mydomain.com/jasper
```

**virtual_forwards**

```
jasper2@mydomain.com myemail@gmail.com
```

And now both the forwards *and* the mailboxes work. (Of course, you could still specify `virtual_alias_maps` as long as you leave that domain out of it (I assume) but I had no use for it, so I removed it entirely.)

Comment: UPDATE: I found that if I used catchall forwarding, I needed to add every other virtual mailbox explicitly forwarding to itself to the forwarding file.

Comment: @BuvinJ I think I've never mixed a virtual forward catchall with virtual mailboxes (in fact, after this one instance, I think I've really just moved away from using virtual mailboxes all together). I'll see if I can reproduce that behavior sometime and then add it to my answer.

Comment: When I did this, I had a catchall vmailbox first.  I tried a few failed combinations of configurations, and saw a post that supposedly the catchall needs to be listed first in the file(s).  You might want to keep these points in mind when you figure out exactly how to do this.  Also, if you don't use vmailboxes now, do you have some other way to add email accounts for non-system users?

Comment: @BuvinJ No, I'm just a hobbyist who didn't really need to have virtual mailboxes to begin with. I'm just too stubborn to let it go when it just inexplicably doesn't work.

Comment: I understand that!  Thanks for the tenaciousness and for sharing your findings here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes works well for me in docker-mailserver.

In your virtual setup file put an override if you want to re-route a certain email.
./CONTAINER/docker-data/dms/config/postfix-virtual.cf

user1@localdomain.bla user1@externaldomain.bla

If you remove the line the email will be delivered locally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).